# Page not disposed when signed up: Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, routes, navigation, provider

I am trying to implement **provider** package to **signUp/signIn/signOut** using Firebase Auth.
My ChangeNotifier class is-

```
import 'package:e_shoppie/db/authentication.dart';
import 'package:e_shoppie/db/user_services.dart';
import 'package:e_shoppie/structure/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

//User can only be one of these states
/**
 * uninitialized: User just opened the app (just opening)
 * unauthenticated: Show the login screen to the user
 * authenticating: Show a circular indicator the user
 * authenticated: User is looged into the app
 */
enum Status { uninitialized, authenticated, authenticating, unauthenticated }

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  Auth _userAuth = Auth();
  UserServices userServices = UserServices();
  User? _user;
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  Status _status =
      Status.uninitialized; //when the instance of the class is created
  UserProvider.initialize() : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance {
    //subscribing to stream to listen to changes in user status
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen(
      (user) {
        _onStatusChanged(user);
      },
    );
  }
  Status get status => _status;
  User? get user => _user;  
Future<bool> signUp(String username, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      //change the status of the user
      _status = Status.authenticating;
      //notify the listeners
      notifyListeners();
      // UserCredential credential =
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      Map<String, dynamic> values = {
        'name': username,
        'email': email,
        'id': user!.uid,
      };
      userServices.createUser(values);
      _status = Status.authenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      _status = Status.unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    print('entered signOut');
    await _auth.signOut();
    _status = Status.unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    print('Exiting signOut');

    return Future.delayed(Duration
        .zero); //duration to return is set to zero (can work without it)
  }

  Future<void> _onStatusChanged(User? user) async {
    if (user == null) {
      _status = Status.unauthenticated;
    } else {
      _user = user;
      _status = Status.authenticated;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The way I am navigating on state change is-

```
class ScreenController extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenController({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    switch (user.status) {
      case Status.uninitialized:
        return SplashScreen();
      case Status.unauthenticated:
        return LoginScreen();
      case Status.authenticating:
        return LoadingScreen();
      case Status.authenticated:
        return HomePage();
      default:
        return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:** in my **SignUp** page, I call the signUp method of the **UserProvider** class to signUp the user.
I expect **the signup page gets destroyed and home page appears when user is created and sign up procedure is complete.**
What I get: **Home Page is built but the sign up page is not destroyed and remains on the screen unless I press the back button.**

**Sign Up button -**

```
                              // minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.,
                              child: Text(
                                'Sign Up and Register',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                if (!await provider.signUp(
                                    _nameTextController.text,
                                    _emailTextController.text,
                                    _passwordTextController.text)) {
                                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                          content: Text('Sign In Failed')));
                                }
                                // Navigator.pop(context);
                                // Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                //     context,
                                //     MaterialPageRoute(
                                //         builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                              },
                            ),
```

Also- my Sign Up class is wrapped with **Consumer**.
I am using the provider package for navigation. The problem I am facing is: that Debug mode shows that the login page is disposed of when the user logs in and Home Page appears. But when I sign in from the Sign Up page, the page is not disposed and Home Page is constructed below it.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context)` or  `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context)`. This is work perfect in your scenario both have the same output difference is only animations. For  signUp/signIn/signOut this is ideal way.

Comment: I am using the provider package for navigation. I understand that the mentioned method is correct and will work perfectly but the problem I am facing does not occur when I login from the login screen. Debug mode shows that login page is disposed when user logs in and Home Page appears. But when I sign in from the Sign Up page, the page is not disposed and Home Page is constructed below it.